# div height overstretching when image is appended

Tags: css, image, height

I'm having a problem with nested divs and their height.

What i want to accomplish is that the an image's parent's height stretch to fit the image. What is happening is that the parent is overstretching and the height is bigger than the image.

you can check the code working here:
http://jsfiddle.net/83Ke6/

HTML

```
<div class="select_box">
    <div class="selected">
        <img src="http://awardwallet.com/images/fbSmallLogo.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.select_box {
    display:inline-block;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
.selected {
    border:1px solid gray;
}
img {
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

So on this case, .selected should equal img height, however it is 5px heigher;
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default img is a inline element and therefore reserves a space under just like lines in a paragraph. Add `display: block;` to the image to remove the spacing.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/83Ke6/3/

Comment: Another option (which fixes the actual problem) is to set the image to `vertical-align: bottom`.

Answer (score 1):

```
.select_box {
    display:inline-block;
    height:auto;
    border:1px solid blue;
    line-height:0px;
}
.selected {
    border:1px solid gray;
    height:auto;
}
img {
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

By setting an auto; height and an line-height of 0px;, your div will adjust to it's inner content. Resulting like this: http://jsfiddle.net/wz45k/

Comment: works perfect, same as @rubelet answer. Hoever ill accept that one since the inline-block; position was the actual problem to my approach